# upgraded seaborn but when running sns.__version__ the version is still the same

Tags: python, seaborn

I think I'm not using the upgraded seaborn. I run `!pip install seaborn --upgrade` to version 0.11.0
However when I run `import seaborn as sns; sns.__version__` I still got 0.10.1

I use Mac OS

Comment: Did you restart the kernel ?

Comment: thanks, that solved the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the kernel and the seaborn version got updated